# How do I create generic sidebars like those found on most websites?

Tags: javascript, html, css

If you have the web page covering the entire screen, there are areas on the left and right, which contain nothing.
If you make the page smaller they will become smaller and the actual webpage stays centered as you move it, until the bars are gone at which point it will stop moving. 
(this website contains those bars)
I looked up how to make side bars but resources I found all contain sidebars which don't disappear, or navigation bars. (I do not want a navigation bar)

Comment: Your description is really unclear.. Any example url? Are you talking about simple centering the div or responsive design?

Comment: Have you tried View Source? Inspect Element? Firebug? Developer's toolbar (F12)?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is kind of vague, but in most situations you have a two column fixed width layout which is wrapped in a container. That container is typically centered on the page with a fixed width.

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="left-column">Left Column</div>
  <div id="right-column">Right Column</div>
</div>
```

In this case, margin:0 auto on the container div is what centers the div. You can use min-width to ensure that the container div doesn't go below a certain size, which would be good if you were using a percentage based layout. The CSS would look something like this: (Note that I've given it height and color to make it clear).

```
#container {
  margin:0 auto;
  width:300px;
  min-width:300px;    
}

#left-column {
  float:left;
  background-color:green;  
  width:230px;
  height:200px;    
}

#right-column {
  float:right;
  background-color: red;
  width:70px;
  height:200px;    
}
```

Here's the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SeasonEnds/jxzGL/).

Comment: Not a problem. Everyone starts somewhere. I would definitely agree with @egrunin that a great way to start is inspecting elements on sites that you like. Also, choosing an answer will ensure people will answer your questions in the future :D

Answer (score 1):

Dustin Diaz used to have a really slick answer to this question - but his site appears to be down (http://www.dustindiaz.com/centering-a-webpage/)

anyways, you can center a webpage without any extra markup by adding this css on your body:

```
body { 
    margin:0 auto;
    width:760px;
    /* adjust width as needed */
}
```

All credit to Dustin.

Answer (score 0):

When you find a site that does what you want, you can see how it works by using the tools that come with your browser. On IE and Chrome, for example, pressing F12 will show you everything - the HTML, javascript, CSS, and so forth.

If there's a particular effect you're having trouble understanding, come back with a URL and we'll help you with the details.